# I have removed the malware from our website however, when I tried again to search the word from Google it is still there

Tags: hacked

I am not sure if this is the right page. But if not, please redirect the correct page.

I have removed the malware from our website however, when I tried again to search the word from Google it is still there.

Kindly please provide help on this or what are the necessary steps that I should take.

Thanks, 
Melissa

Comment: Your question is not related to WordPress.However, answer for your question is, Give time to Google. Google need time to crawl your website.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home (you need a gmail account – since it's Google)
Add your website to the platform and ask Google to scan your website for any more malware.

It might take 24-48 hours. Once Google is happy that there are no more issues, your website ratings will be restored.